# changing Reference of an object when its source changes in java

Tags: java, object, interface, reference, static

This seems to be an easy question, but i cant figure it out

I have as University-Homework programmed a game, consisting of a "game" class, that implements an Interface and a "CLI" Class, that uses that Interface to allow User Inputs  for the game.
Now saving and loading had to be added, which works, but the professor dosent like, that the object is being returned after loading in the "CLI" and used there. Instead he wants it in an static reference in the Class "game" and the "CLI" to use that.

My question is since the object is being used over an Interface is there a way to make the Interface automatically update the used reference, when the static variable is being changed?

I know that you cant make a new object with an old reference, so it has to be updated somehow

Comment: There's not really a way to "automatically update a reference."  (Your design is honestly better than what your professor supposedly asked for.)

Comment: I'm stuggling to follow exactly what you're doing.  I think some code would make this question much easier to understand.  You don't need to post any of the actual project code, just like a quick outline so we can see the structure of what you're talking about.

Answer (score 0):

My professor was "hinting" at a Singleton: A static Method that returns the value of a static variable and if the variable is empty generates a new object to fill that variable.